# next.js error while trying to run code on liveserver

Tags: npm, terminal, next.js, localhost

I am getting this error:

```
Failed to compile
./utils/styles.js
Error: failed to process internal error: entered unreachable code: assign property in object literal is invalid
This error occurred during the build process and can only be dismissed by fixing the error.
```

while trying to open my code on localhost through terminal.

Comment: There is not much info in your question, but it might be something like using `=` instead of `:` when setting state in a constructor in React.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah had same error, you probably used `=` instead of `:` in your object. Example;
`const myObj = {name = "Usman"}` instead of `const myObj = {name : 'Usman}`

Comment: Came here with this error, as soon as I read your answer I face palmed, so obvious, yet so easy to not notice.  Thanks!